# Bitwise Operation confusion

Tags: c, hex, logic, operations

Firstly, let me just state for the record that this is in prep for a midterm I have Wednesday. 
I'm taking a C Programming course and we've barely even touched Bitwise Operations, but we're being tested on them.

For instance, we're supposed to know something like what A, B, C, and D are initialized as in code like this:

```
unsigned int A, B, C, D;
A = 0xfedc & 0x300c;
B = 0xba98 | 0x1236;
C = 0x7654 ^ 0xfa00;
D = ~0xffff3210;
```

If possible, could you provide me with a decent tutorial/guide for understanding these concepts? An explanation would be awesome too, but I'd prefer not to be handed an actual answer explanation.

Thanks in advance for any help you can spare me.

Comment: Those are not logic operators, but bitwise operators.

Comment: Funnily enough, my teacher called them logic operations, hence why I used that. I thought they were really bitwise though. My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologise. Especially if your teacher called them thus. And one can view them as applying logic operations on pairs of corresponding bits [for `~` of course not on pairs] simultaneously, so it's not completely wrong, just unusual - except that the part of the processor doing these operations is called the Arithmetic _Logic_ unit, so it's not _so_ unusual. But calling them bitwise operators to distinguish them from `&&` and `||` has - obvious, I believe - advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is:

- Do you recognize `&` as bitwise AND, `|` as bitwise OR, `^` as bitwise XOR, and `~` as bitwise NOT?

If not, you've got a problem or two and need to get to the point of recognizing them all.

Then you need to know what each operation means...

- For a given bit position, if both bits are `1`, then `b1 & b2` will be `1`; otherwise, it will be `0`.
- For a given bit position, if both bits are `0`, then `b1 | b2` will be `0`; otherwise, it will be `1`.
- For a given bit position, if the two bits are the same (both `0` or both `1`), then `b1 ^ b2` will be `0`; otherwise it will be `1`.
- For a given bit position, if the bit is `0`, `~b1` will be `1`; otherwise, it will be `0`.

You also need to recognize that the hex representation is closely related to the bit patterns in the number.

- 0x0 ⟶ 0000<sub>2</sub>
- 0x1 ⟶ 0001<sub>2</sub>
- ...
- 0xE ⟶ 1110<sub>2</sub>
- 0xF ⟶ 1111<sub>2</sub>

Combining these, you can deduce the answers for the questions shown, applying the bitwise operators to each bit of the operands.

Comment: I'm in a class right now, so I can't write a full response. However I definitely understand that first line you've got there. The main thing is that I need to figure out if the pattern behind the bits and hex. I don't have either memorized right now.

Comment: While I think I have an handle on the overlying logic, could you explain what you mean by using the subscript after eat binary number?

Comment: The subscript 2 simply indicates that the binary number is a binary number; I could have used 16 as a subscript on the LHS, but the 0x prefix is unambiguous too.  There isn't a standard way to represent binary numbers in C; you'll occasionally see 0b1111 or something similar used; this is unambiguous but non-standard, so I didn't use it.

Comment: FWIW: `A = 0x300C`, `B = 0xBABE`, `C = 0x8C54`, `D = 0x0000CDEF`, as no doubt you could demonstrate for yourself by writing a trivial program to do the printing.  Your homework is making sure you know why those answers are correct.

Comment: Yeah I figured that part out fortunately. The unfortunate thing is that my teacher has us handwrite code during exams - no computers. So this really is all by hand/brain. If I had a computer, I could go with trial and error and figure it out much easier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html